# Rendering array of file names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to print list of files from current directory. 
I used

```
@files = Dir.glob('*')
```

and in views i'm trying to print using

```
<%= @files.each {|file| puts "<li>" + file + "</li>"}%>
```

But instead it prints me just array of filenames, without `<li>` tag. WHat am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you ensured you're viewing the raw output, not rendered in the browser's viewport?

Comment: here is what i see in browser http://d.pr/i/SLoU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As alex said, puts will probably push it to server logs, here's what you can do:

```
<% @files.each do |file| %>
  <li><%= file %></li>
<% end %>
```

Since you have the = before the @files, you're seeing the string output of an array.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
<% @files.each do |file| %>
<li> <%= file %></li>
<% end %>
```

You seem to not get the syntax of erb syntax right.

`puts` will print the values in logfile not on webpage

Answer (score 2):

in helper

```
def display_files(dir='*')
 list = ""
 files = Dir.glob(dir)
 @files.each do |file|
  list << "<li>#{file}</li>"
 end
list

end
```

In view